# When adding requestMatchers to permitAll in filter SecurityFilterChain method throw an exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to configure spring security in my project spring-boot 3.1.2 project to secure all my endpoints except the register endpoint. The following is my security configuration class

package com.example.demo.config;

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService detailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(detailsService);
        return new ProviderManager(daoAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

}
```

When I run my project I get the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name         'filterChain' defined in class path resource \[com/example/demo/config/SecurityConfig.class\]: Failed to instantiate \[org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain\]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).
```

Comment: Try `requestMatchers("/auth/register/**").permitAll()`

Comment: Try `antMatcher` instead

Comment: @wnotunas `In Spring Security 6.0, antMatchers() as well as other configuration methods for securing requests (namely mvcMatchers() and regexMatchers() ) have been removed from the API.`

Comment: @AndreiLisa thanks for notifying me, he didn't provide us the version he's using. I'm currently using `antMatcher` with `spring-boot version 2.7 vs java 1.8` and it still works for me, moreover, I did have annotation like your solution below, but in case his code doesn't work as expected, just try `antMatcher` if he uses older version of spring security which we didn't know about.

Comment: Spring Boot 3 is compatible only with Spring Security 6.x

Answer (score 1):

For more details, please check it: [cve-2023-34035](https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-34035)

to fix it: remove `@EnableWebMvc` and add `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation to your security configuration class.